# Get string of temp file and add custom folder

Tags: c++, visual-studio, visual-c++

I'm new to C++ and I have been thinking how to get string of the user's temp folder on Windows and append to it a custom folder name.

e.g `"\Users\user\AppData\Local\Temp\NameOfCustomFolder"`

I've tried this:

```
    std::string szOutput{};
    TCHAR path_buf[MAX_PATH];
    DWORD ret_val = GetTempPath(MAX_PATH, path_buf);
    if (ret_val > MAX_PATH || (ret_val == 0))
    {
        std::cout << "GetTempPath failed";
    }
    else
    {
        szOutput = path_buf, "NameOfCustomFolder\\file.exe"
    }

    return szOutput;
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This does not perform the string concatenation you want

```
szOutput = path_buf, "NameOfCustomFolder\\file.exe";
```

Rather do

```
szOutput = std::string{path_buf} + "NameOfCustomFolder\\file.exe";
```

Answer (score 0):

If you can use C++17, I would suggest [std::filesystem::path::append](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/filesystem/path/append)

It will take care of the path separators, and will make it easy to go cross-platform.